# How can I troubleshoot a FREQUENCY formula to index unique values in array?

Tags: excel, frequency

I am trying return unique values from a third column if the values on the first and the second column match. I have been able to get the array formula below to work:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384,SMALL(IF(C$3:W$3=Funding!$J4:$J3385, ROW(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}
```

However when I try to insert the FREQUENCY function I get an error:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384,SMALL(IF(C$3:W$3=Funding!$J3:$J3384, ROW(FREQUENCY(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384,Funding!$A$3:$A$3384)),ROW(1:1)-1),1)),"")}

**Column A**  **Column B**  **Column C**  **Column D**
     11            1             1            **11**
     22            1             1            **22** 
     33            3             3            **33**
     44            7             0
     55            5             0
     66            5             0
```

Columns B and C have 1,1 and 3 in common therefore the indexed values in Column A (11,22 and 33) are returned in Column D.

Comment: Your narrative does not match your formulas; there is no 'second column'. Please provide sample data together with expected results (**not** in image form).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question with the additional details requested

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.